# How to smooth (slow down) aircraft acceleration in Unity2D?

Tags: physics, unity3d-2dtools

I asked this question on Unity forums, but they seem much less populated than SO, and I did not get an acceptable answer. The question is as follows: in my game (made in Unity, C#), I use physics (Rigidbody2D) and addForce to accelerate the aircraft. The force added is proportional to thrust.

The problem is: if I add a lot of force, I reach realistically high speeds unrealistically quickly. If I add less force, I have realistic acceleration, but snails' top speed. I tried to play with drag, but the equation evens itself out: twice less force with twice less drag produce same acceleration and top speed. Increasing mass slows acceleration, but proportionally reduces max speed.

What I am doing now is having several drag equations depending on player's speed to limit the acceleration down to manageable levels, but it feels very clunky (not to mention unintuitive and unrealistic).

Here are snippets of my code:

```
 //////////////////Adding thrust/////////////////////////////
 rb.AddForce(transform.right*thrust); //thrust goes from 0 to 100
 //////////////////Drag equations/////////////////////////////
     if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= 3)
           rb.drag = Mathf.Clamp(-rb.velocity.magnitude / 8f + 4f, 2.1f, 4f);
     else if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= 4)
           rb.drag = Mathf.Clamp(-rb.velocity.magnitude / 4.9f + 4f, 2.1f, 4f);
     else if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= 7) 
           rb.drag = Mathf.Clamp(-rb.velocity.magnitude / 2.9f + 4.15f, 1.1f, 4f);
     else if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= 10)
           rb.drag = Mathf.Clamp(-rb.velocity.magnitude / 5f + 3.2f, 1f, 4f);
     else
           rb.drag = Mathf.Clamp(-rb.velocity.magnitude / 18f + 1.7f, 0.8f, 4f);
```

Speed conversion from units to km/h is as follows:

```
 speedText.text = "Speed: " + Mathf.Round(rb.velocity.magnitude * 50 * 3.6f) + "km/h";
```

So rb.velocity.magnitude of 7 is 1260 km/h.

Without my drag equations the craft either boosts to 2500km/h almost instantly, or slowly accelerates to 500km/h and stays there. Am I missing something? How can I have high top speed AND slow acceleration?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that the latter option ("slowly accelerates to 500km/h and stays there") is what you want, but it's a matter of tweaking the values. If you want to avoid if statements, try playing around with different equations you multiply the drag or velocity by. For example, http://i.imgur.com/FACzbsQ.png. You could also use `log()` and `sqrt()` but those are slow. Good luck!

Comment: Whoa, mate, your idea totally worked! Thank you so much! So, you said that my drag equation idea was generally right and provided a nice starter function. But it was not perfect, so I googled "S-shaped function" and found a "sigmoid" function, which is absolutely perfect for this case! After an hour or so of tinkering, I found the shape which works great for me (maybe it'll help somebody with a similar problem): 6/(1+e^(0.18(x-0.5)))+0.35.

Comment: That's awesome, I'm glad it worked out! Thanks for sharing the equation, I gotta look into that myself haha

Comment: @flanker37 You should add your equation as an answer and accept it, that way people will easier see that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to meepzh's idea, I was able to find a working solution: I found a "sigmoid" function, here's the equation that works great in my case: `6/(1+e^(0.18(x-0.5)))+0.35.`